# Apache does not see files under overlay mount

Tags: apache-httpd, overlayfs

have mounted overlay fs:

```
overlay on /srv/www/site type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/srv/www/site_orig,upperdir=/srv/www/site_custom,workdir=/srv/www/overlay_workdir)
```

I can see and edit files under /srv/www/site, but apache shows that dir is empty. 
I tried to direct apache's doc root to /srv/www/site, to /srv/www; tried to remove PrivateTmp option from systemd service, but that didn't help.

```
sudo -u http /srv/www/site
```

works - I can see the files. (apache runs as http user)
Permissions are correct.

```
cat /proc/<apache_pid>/mountinfo
```

doesn't show this mount

Kernel 4.14.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that not the httpd was in slave namespace, but my entire X session with all graphic terminals.

So I removed `PrivateTmp=yes` from **sddm.service**, and now Apache process can see my mounts